# Perl pack/unpack and length of binary string

Tags: perl, arrays, pack, unpack

Consider this short example:

```
$a = pack("d",255);
print length($a)."\n";
# Prints 8

$aa = pack("ddddd", 255,123,0,45,123);
print length($aa)."\n";
# Prints 40

@unparray = unpack("d "x5, $aa);
print scalar(@unparray)."\n";
# Prints 5

print length($unparray[0])."\n"
# Prints 3

printf "%d\n", $unparray[0] '
# Prints 255

# As a one-liner:
# perl -e '$a = pack("d",255); print length($a)."\n"; $aa = pack("dd", 255,123,0,45,123); print length($aa)."\n"; @unparray = unpack("d "x5, $aa); print scalar(@unparray)."\n"; print length($unparray[0])."\n"; printf "%d\n", $unparray[0] '
```

Now, I'd expect a double-precision float to be eight bytes, so the first `length($a)` is correct. But why is the length after the unpack (`length($unparray[0])`) reporting 3 - when I'm trying to go back the exact same way (double-precision, i.e. eight bytes) - and the value of the item (255) is correctly preserved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By unpacking what you packed, you've gotten back the original values, and the first value is 255. The stringification of 255 is "255", which is 3 characters long, and that's what `length` tells you.

Comment: Thanks for that @hobbs; pack goes from Integer to "double-value packed bytestring"; and for the other way around (unpack), I expected somehow I'd get from  "double-value packed bytestring" to double-precision floats in `$unparray`; but it seems those are strings in `$unparray`! Thanks for clarifying this - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau, You do get double-precision floats in `@unparray`. `length`  finds the length of string, so it requires a string, so it will stringify its argument if required.

Comment: Thanks for that @ikegami - the "`length` finds the length of string" seems to have been the stumbling block which I failed to understand.. Cheers!