# How do I unpack a double-precision value in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, unpack

From this question:

[bytearray - Perl pack/unpack and length of binary string - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320880/perl-pack-unpack-and-length-of-binary-string)

I've learned that `@unparray = unpack("d "x5, $aa);` in the snippet below results with string items in the `unparray` - not with double precision numbers (as I expected).

Is it possible to somehow obtain an array of double-precision values from the `$aa` bytestring in the snippet below?:

```
$a = pack("d",255);
print length($a)."\n";
# prints 8

$aa = pack("ddddd", 255,123,0,45,123);
print length($aa)."\n";
# prints 40

@unparray = unpack("d "x5, $aa);
print scalar(@unparray)."\n";
# prints 5

print length($unparray[0])."\n" 
# prints 3

printf "%d\n", $unparray[0] '
# prints 255

# one liner:
# perl -e '$a = pack("d",255); print length($a)."\n"; $aa = pack("ddddd", 255,123,0,45,123); print length($aa)."\n"; @unparray = unpack("d "x5, $aa); print scalar(@unparray)."\n"; print length($unparray[0])."\n" '
```

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think it's not stored as a double?

```
use feature qw( say );

use Config      qw( %Config );
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );

my @a = unpack "d5", pack "d5", 255,123,0,45,123;

say 0+@a;             # 5
Dump $a[0];           # NOK (floating point format)
say $Config{nvsize};  # 8 byte floats on this build
```

Comment: Many thanks for this snippet, @ikegami -  so now I know how to check for the stored datatypes (didn't know about `Dump`).. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but you've misunderstood hobbs' answer to your earlier question.

`$unparray[0]` **is** a double-precision floating-point value; but `length` is not like (say) C's `sizeof` operator, and doesn't tell you the size of its argument. Rather, it converts its argument to a string, and then tells you the length of that string.

For example, this:

```
my $a = 3.0 / 1.5;
print length($a), "\n";
```

will print this:

```
1
```

because it sets `$a` to `2.0`, which gets stringified as `2`, which has length `1`.

Comment: Indeed, `length` is like C's `strlen` (but smarter, since it will convert the argument to a string if you didn't pass a string).

Comment: @ikegami: Indeed! Also smarter in that it's not fooled by strings that contain `'\0'`, and in that it takes O(1) time if the argument already has its stringified version ready . . . but now I feel like an infomercial. "But that's not all, folks. If you call *right now*, `length` will also handle strings of Unicode characters, at no extra charge!"

Comment: @rukah, `length` doesn't actually known anything about Unicode. It simply return the number of characters in the string. Those characters could be bytes, Unicode code points, temperature samplings, whatever. It's actually not that appropriate for Unicode as it returns neither the number of grapheme clusters nor the visual width of the string.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, yeah, but if it's a string of Unicode characters, then `length` returns the number of characters (code-points), which is frequently "good enough". (But a count of grapheme clusters would *rock*!) If you try to use C's `strlen` on a UTF-16 or UTF-32 string, it'll be fooled by null bytes, and if you try to use C's `strlen` on a UTF-8 string, it'll be fooled by non-ASCII characters' multibyte representations.

Comment: There is talk of adding [Unicode::GCString](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::GCString) to the Perl dist. It has functions that do just that.

Comment: Many thanks for the discussion, all - indeed, I had misunderstood the answer on previous question - however, the discussion here helped correct that! Cheers!